# Enterprise distribution of application

Tags: ios

I am developing an application which will be distributed with many features.
After 15 days, I want to disable some of the features of this application and make them as paid features. Is this allowed according to the apple standards?

Answer (score 0):

Well as far as I know, you can monetise your application however you like, but if you use in-app purchases some money will go to Apple. As for enabling/disabling features, that should be fine.

Comment: Thank you!!There is another scenario. I have an application loaded with a bundle of features that can be used for 15 days free of cost. After 15 days all the features become paid. In other words, whole application becomes paid. If the user does not pay for the application after 15 days, he/she would not be able to use the application. Can the user uninstall and install the application again from itunes store and again use it for free for another 15 days??

Comment: It depends how you implement the feature blocking. I know apps where you can simply delete the cache to reset the free trial period. You would need to have the app connect to a server to determine whether the users trial period is over if you want to prevent the reset. However, the apps i know of have many premium version sales even though resetting them is very easy so the implementation is your choice. Don't forget to set best answer if it helped!